# UITableView Custom Cell is duplicating UIButton on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that contains a number of custom `UITableViewCells` types.

One of these types simply is a cell containing a `UIStackView` that itself contains one or more `UIButton`'s.

When scrolling off screen and back on, the buttons are being added again. This happens on each scroll event.

[Pre Scroll Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJPWf.png)
[Post Scroll Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twmBJ.png)

I understand that as a cell is reused for performance potentially what is happening is my setup code in `cellForRowAt` where I configure a cell is being executed again.

Hence it is adding 3 buttons from the data source, to the cell, which already contains buttons from the last render.

I do not understand how I can clear this up and prevent this behaviour however and would very much appreciated someone offering an insight as I am lost.

I have been able to prepare a small app that recreates this as I cannot share my current project as it is closed source.

I apologise for the mountain of code below, this is however the minimum required to simply drop into a project and recreate.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let textCellId = "textCellId"
    let buttonCellId = "buttonCellId"

    // MARK: - Mock Data Source

    let cellContent = [
        Message(type: .buttonGroup, buttonGroup: [
            MessageButton(label: "Button #1"),
            MessageButton(label: "Button #2"),
            MessageButton(label: "Button #3")
        ]),
        Message(type: .text, text: "A"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "B"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "C"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "D"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "E"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "F"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "G"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "H"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "I"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "J"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "K"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "L"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "M"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "N"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "O"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "P"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "Q"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "R"),
        Message(type: .text, text: "S"),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        registerCells()
        configureTableView()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellContent.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: buttonCellId, for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell
            cell.buttonGroupContent = item.buttonGroup
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellId, for: indexPath) as! TextCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = item.text
            return cell
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Misc TableView Setup

extension TableViewController {

    fileprivate func registerCells() {
        tableView.register(TextCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: textCellId)
        tableView.register(ButtonCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: buttonCellId)
    }

    fileprivate func configureTableView() {
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}

// MARK: - Cell Types

class TextCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    var buttonGroupContent: [MessageButton]? {
        didSet {
            anchorSubViews()
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    fileprivate var button: UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return button
    }

    fileprivate let buttonGroupStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem
        return stackView
    }()
}

extension ButtonCell {
    fileprivate func anchorSubViews() {
        guard let buttons = buttonGroupContent?.enumerated() else { return }

        for (index, b) in buttons {
            let btn = button
            btn.setTitle(b.label, for: .normal)
            btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
            btn.tag = index
            buttonGroupStackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
        }

        addSubview(buttonGroupStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttonGroupStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            buttonGroupStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            buttonGroupStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            buttonGroupStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
            ])
    }
}





// MARK: - Misc for setup

struct MessageButton {
    let label: String
}

enum MessageType {
    case text, buttonGroup
}

struct Message {
    let type: MessageType
    let text: String?
    let buttonGroup: [MessageButton]?

    init(type: MessageType, text: String? = nil, buttonGroup: [MessageButton]? = nil) {
        self.type = type
        self.text = text
        self.buttonGroup = buttonGroup
    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for your comment, both my cells have a unique identifier so I am unsure how to interpret your suggestion as a fix? thank you

Comment: @IanBell please provide more context around answer. Links to off site content can change / break and reduce the usefulness of this answer for other users in future.

Comment: @nodediggity : you're right, I had no time but I wanted to help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because cells are reusable, content stays. So your old buttons are still in your stack view and you're adding next buttons every time.

To fix this, before you add new buttons to `UIStackView` remove old buttons

```
extension ButtonCell {

    fileprivate func anchorSubViews() {
        ...

        for case let button as UIButton in buttonGroupStackView.subviews {
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        for (index, b) in buttons {
            ...
            buttonGroupStackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
        }    
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `button` and `buttonGroupStackView` properties optional and `weak`. The `addSubview` method on will retain a strong reference to it's subview. So it never gets removed. And override `prepareForReuse()` to do whatever cleanup necessary and make sure the stackview has been removed from the cell. Here's how you could do it:

```
class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    var buttonGroupContent: [MessageButton]? {
        didSet {
            anchorSubViews()
        }
    }
    fileprivate weak var buttonGroupStackView: UIStackView?

    // MARK: - Initialization
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.initialSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initialSetup()
    }

    private func initialSetup() -> Void {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseSystem

        self.addSubview(stackView)
        self.buttonGroupStackView = stackView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
            ])
    }

    // MARK: - Subclass Overrides
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        self.buttonGroupStackView?.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview()} )
    }

    // MARK: - Private
    fileprivate func createButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return button
    }

}

extension ButtonCell {
    fileprivate func anchorSubViews() {
        guard let buttons = buttonGroupContent?.enumerated() else { return }

        for (index, b) in buttons {
            let btn = self.createButton()
            btn.setTitle(b.label, for: .normal)
            btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
            btn.tag = index
            self.buttonGroupStackView?.addArrangedSubview(btn)
        }
    }
}
```

It is always recommended to use a `weak` reference to subviews or `IBOutlet` properties unless you require otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, trying this however means no buttons at all are rendered. I appreciate your input, thank you.

Comment: @blukkublukku Ah, I see why. I forgot to add the stackview as a subview once it has been initialized. Since we changed it to weak, it will be deallocated immediately if not added to subview. I've made necessary edits, check them out and let me know if it works

Comment: I have added your suggestions and now see the following error: `Value of type '(ButtonCell) -> () -> (ButtonCell)' has no member 'addSubview'`

Comment: @blukkublukku As I said, I typed it on the SO editor so there may be syntax and/or compiler errors that I might have overlooked. I updated my answer. This time tested on iOS simulator with Xcode. Should work now